# error in calling checkpoints in tensor flow on windows

Tags: tensorflow

I have neural network model which uses tensor flow and checkpoints. When i am running that on mac (as it was created on mac) it runs well but the same code on windows platform it gives error that two checkpoints have different inputs.So it is platform issue or there are  some packages which needs to be installed. I have copied the error below.

> Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [108,100]
>   rhs shape= [133,100]   [[Node: save/Assign_1 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@fc1/kernel"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](fc1/kernel, save/RestoreV2:1)]]

Comment: I think you need to give bit more details. Answerers will find it hard to find interest in your question if you don't explain it well

Comment: we have a model(gradient descent) which we are running. it got checkpoints (graphs) in it. When we run it on jupyter notebook on mac os, it runs well and reads the checkpoint graphs but when we run the same thing on windows environment the code gives the error as mentioned above. the real problem is to how make it run on windows .